# Render from a callback function - typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, render

While using a graphql query, I am calling a `showUsers` function which is supposed to show all the users (the stying is done so that they can appear as boxes). However, currently nothing shows up.

I am using a functional component, not class component.

This function is called after my `handleSubmitForm`. Here I call `showUsers`.

```
  const getFriendId = React.useCallback(
    (data) => {
      if (data) {
        if (data.users.nodes.length == 0) {
          Alert.alert('User Not Found');
        } else {
          const numberOfUsers = data.users.nodes.length;
          showUsers(data, numberOfUsers);
          addFriend(Number(data.users.nodes[0].id));
        }
      }
    },
    [addFriend],
  );
```

showUsers():

```
   const showUsers = React.useCallback(
     (data: UsersLazyQueryHookResult, numberOfUsers: Number) => {
       for (var i = 0; i < numberOfUsers; i++) {
         const userId = data.users.nodes[i].id;
         const userName = (data.users.nodes[i].firstName).concat((data.users.nodes[i].lastName));
         return(
           <View style={styles.friends}>
             <View style={styles.item}>
              <Text>{userName}</Text>
             </View>
           </View>
         )
       }      
     },
     [createUserRelationMutation],
   );
```

This is how my form looks like. I guess I have to make an edit here but I am not sure how.

```
return (
    <Modal
      visible={showAddFriendEmailPage}
      animationType="slide"
      transparent={true}>
      <SafeAreaView>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.searchTopContainer}>
            <View>
              <Formik
                initialValues={initialValues}
                onSubmit={handleSubmitForm}
                validationSchema={validationSchema}>
                {({ handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit, values }) => (
                  <View style={styles.searchFieldContainer}>
                    <View style={styles.form}>
                      <FieldInput
                        handleChange={handleChange}
                        handleBlur={handleBlur}
                        value={values.email}
                        fieldType="email"
                      />
                      <ErrorMessage
                        name="email"
                        render={msg => (
                          <Text style={styles.errorText}>{msg}</Text>
                        )}
                      />
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                      <Button
                        onPress={handleSubmit}>
                        <Text >Add Friend </Text>
                      </Button>
                    </View>
                  </View>
                )}
              </Formik>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </Modal>
  );
};
```

Note: I only want them to show up below the button, after I submit the form.

EDIT:

I am trying this but I have a few problems:

1. Even when there's only one user, I see the `LOOP`output on the console at least 4 times.
2. Once the query and mutation run successfully and a user is also rendered/displayed, I can no longer press the button again. Which means that I can no longer submit the form and re-run queries or mutations with a different email input.

```
export const AddFriendEmailPage: React.FunctionComponent<AddFriendEmailPageProps> = ({
  toggleShowPage,
  showAddFriendEmailPage,
}) => {
  const initialValues: FormValues = {
    email: '',
  };

  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState<UsersLazyQueryHookResult>('');
  const [numberOfUsers, setNumberOfUsers] = useState('');
  const validationSchema = emailValidationSchema;

  useEffect(() => {
    setUserData(userData);
    setNumberOfUsers(numberOfUsers);
  }, [userData, numberOfUsers]);


  const showAlert = () => {
    Alert.alert('Friend Added');
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (showAddFriendEmailPage) return;
    initialValues.email = '';
  }, [showAddFriendEmailPage]);

  const _onLoadUserError = React.useCallback((error: ApolloError) => {
    setErrorMessage(error.message);
    Alert.alert('Unable to Add Friend');
  }, []);

  const [
    createUserRelationMutation,
    {
      data: addingFriendData,
      loading: addingFriendLoading,
      error: addingFriendError,
      called: isMutationCalled,
    },
  ] = useCreateUserRelationMutation({
    onCompleted: (data: CreateUserRelationMutationResult) => {
      showAlert();
    },
  });

   const showUsers = React.useCallback(
     (data: UsersLazyQueryHookResult, numberOfUsers: Number) => {
       console.log('Number of Users in Loop: ', numberOfUsers);
       for (var i = 0; i < numberOfUsers; i++) {
         const userId = data.users.nodes[i].id;
         const userName = ((data.users.nodes[i].firstName).concat(' ')).concat(data.users.nodes[i].lastName);
         console.log('Whats the Id', userId);
         console.log('UserName', userName);
         console.log('Loop');
         return(
           <View style={styles.friends}>
             <View style={styles.item}>
              <Text>{userName}</Text>
             </View>
           </View>
         )
       }      
     },
     [createUserRelationMutation],
   );

  const addFriend = React.useCallback(
    (id: Number) => {
      console.log('Whats the Id', id);
      createUserRelationMutation({
        variables: {
          input: { relatedUserId: id, type: RelationType.Friend, userId: 7 },
        },
      });
    },
    [createUserRelationMutation],
  );

  const getFriendId = React.useCallback(
    (data: UsersLazyQueryHookResult) => {
      if (data) {
        if (data.users.nodes.length == 0) {
          setErrorMessage('User Not Found');
          Alert.alert('User Not Found');
        } else {
          setUserData(data);
          //const numberOfUsers = data.users.nodes.length;
          setNumberOfUsers(data.users.nodes.length);
          showUsers(data, Number(numberOfUsers));
          addFriend(Number(data.users.nodes[0].id));
        }
      }
    },
    [addFriend],
  );

  const [loadUsers] = useUsersLazyQuery({
    onCompleted: getFriendId,
    onError: _onLoadUserError,
  });

  const handleSubmitForm = React.useCallback(
    (values: FormValues, helpers: FormikHelpers<FormValues>) => {
      console.log('Submitted');
      loadUsers({
        variables: {
          where: { email: values.email },
        },
      });
      values.email = '';
    },
    [loadUsers],
  );

  if (!addingFriendLoading && isMutationCalled) {
    if (addingFriendError) {
      setErrorMessage(addingFriendError.message);
      Alert.alert('Unable to Add Friend');
    }
  }

  return (
    <Modal
      visible={showAddFriendEmailPage}
      animationType="slide"
      transparent={true}>
      <SafeAreaView>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.searchTopContainer}>
            <View style={styles.searchTopTextContainer}>
              <Text
                style={styles.searchCancelDoneText}
                onPress={toggleShowPage}>
                Cancel
              </Text>
              <Text style={styles.searchTopMiddleText}>
                Add Friend by Email
              </Text>
              <Text style={styles.searchCancelDoneText}>Done</Text>
            </View>
            <View>
              <Formik
                initialValues={initialValues}
                onSubmit={handleSubmitForm}
                validationSchema={validationSchema}>
                {({ handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit, values }) => (
                  <View style={styles.searchFieldContainer}>
                    <View style={styles.form}>
                      <FieldInput
                        handleChange={handleChange}
                        handleBlur={handleBlur}
                        value={values.email}
                        fieldType="email"
                      />
                      <ErrorMessage
                        name="email"
                        render={msg => (
                          <Text style={styles.errorText}>{msg}</Text>
                        )}
                      />
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                      <Button
                        rounded
                        style={styles.button}
                        onPress={handleSubmit}>
                        <Text style={styles.text}>Add Friend </Text>
                      </Button>
                    </View>
                  </View>
                )}
              </Formik>
            </View>
            {showUsers(userData, Number(numberOfUsers))}
          </View>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </Modal>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> While using a graphql query, I am calling a `showUsers` function which
>   is supposed to show all the users (the stying is done so that they can
>   appear as boxes). However, currently nothing shows up.

A function call `showUsers(data, numberOfUsers);` can't just show items. You have to render it somewhere.

```
<View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
  <Button
    rounded
    style={styles.button}
    onPress={handleSubmit}>
    <Text style={styles.text}>Add Friend </Text>
  </Button>
</View>
{showUsers(data, numberOfUsers)}
```

But this also don't work straight away because you don't have `data` variable in this context. You have to use `useState`. I don't know if you can use `React.useCallback` function to return component this way. I would change `showUsers(data, numberOfUsers)` to 
separate functional component.

Comment: How could I make it a separate component and still make it work? Could you see my attempt in the edited qs?

Comment: you have to return something after the `for` loop. `numberOfUsers` might be 0 and it won't subbranch

Comment: You have to add `useState` and change `getFriendId` function so it saves data somewhere

Comment: Kinda works but I am still facing an issue. Could you have a look at the edited qs please?